# XeLaTeX и стили (толщина) шрифта

Tags: шрифты, latex

В XeLaTeX есть определение

```
\setsansfont{Akrobat}
```

Сам шрифт имеет 8 начертаний, от ExtraLight до ExtraBold. Начертания касаются только толщины, курсива нет. Как сделать так, чтобы по-умолчанию использовался Light, а не Regular? Помогло:

```
\setsansfont{Akrobat Light}
```

Насколько нормальный такой подход? Кроме того хотелось бы, чтобы некоторые заголовки выводились Black, а не Bold

```
\titleformat
{\chapter} % command
[display]  % shape
{\Huge\bf} % format 
{
\raggedleft
{
    \bfseries\sf\fontsize{48pt}{48pt}\selectfont Часть
        \chn\fontsize{82pt}{20pt}\selectfont\color[rgb]{0.2,0.2,0.2}\thechapter} 
} % label
{-6pt} % sep
{  
    \titlerule[2.5pt]
    \vspace{1.5pt}
    \titlerule[1.5pt]
} % before-code
```

Comment: Здесь вам дадут более подробный ответ: https://tex.stackexchange.com